# Visual studio 2017 ユーザマクロの値の変更

Tags: visual-studio

Visual studio 2017を使用しています。

プロジェクトファイルでユーザマクロを追加して値を設定したのですが、
プロジェクトファイルにユーザマクロを追加したのは、プロジェクトファイルに以下の2行を追加しました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

プロジェクトファイルでマクロにしたのは、頻繁に使用するキーワードの修正を1か所修正すれば、変更できるようにするという意図の基で行いました。

これをプロパティダイアログで値を変更する方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか？
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=vs-2019
を見て、「編集」→ 「マクロ｝の操作で、
ユーザマクロの一覧とその値を、プロパティダイアログで参照する方法は分かったのですが、

その値を変更する方法がが分かりません。

どなたかご教授下さい。

編集→マクロと遷移した画面を以下に示します。
イメージ説明 
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上図で選択状態になっているのが、新しく追加したマクロです。 
このマクロの値を変えたいのです。

プロパティマネージャ
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/257570

Comment: teratailで受けた指摘・質問をもう一度こちらでも受けるおつもりでしょうか。質問を改善されては。

Comment: 初めに「プロジェクトファイルでユーザマクロを追加して値を設定した」時の手順をもう一度書き出してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 手段が目的化しています。なぜその値を変更したいのか、目的を明らかにすべきです。

Comment: 質問の内容を編集しました。

Comment: 「頻繁に使用するキーワード」とはどこで使用されるものですか？ C/C++プログラム内ですか？ 使用目的に合わせて手段が変わってきます。

Answer (score 0):

参照記事を下の方にたどっていくと、以下の項目が出てきます。
この同じ手順で追加したマクロの値を変更できると思われます。

[ユーザー定義マクロを作成するには](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=vs-2019#to-create-a-user-defined-macro)

> 1. **[プロパティマネージャー]** ウィンドウを開きます。 (メニューバーで、**表示** > **プロパティマネージャー** または > **その他の Windows** > **プロパティマネージャー** を **表示** します。)プロパティシート (名前の末尾が. user) のショートカットメニューを開き、**プロパティ** を選択します。 そのプロパティ シートの **[プロパティ ページ]** ダイアログ ボックスが開きます。
> 2. ダイアログ ボックスの左ウィンドウで、 **[ユーザー マクロ]** を選びます。 右ウィンドウで **[マクロの追加]** ボタンを選んで、 **[ユーザー マクロの追加]** ダイアログ ボックスを開きます。
> 3. ダイアログ ボックスで、マクロの名前と値を指定します。 必要に応じて、 **[ビルド環境でこのマクロを環境変数として設定します]** チェック ボックスをオンにします。

プロパティマネージャー表示
[image: プロパティマネージャー表示]

プロパティページダイアログボックスのユーザーマクロ表示
[image: プロパティページダイアログボックスのユーザーマクロ表示]

マクロ編集ダイアログ表示(上記ダイアログのマクロ名＆値欄をダブルクリックして表示)
[image: マクロ編集ダイアログ表示]

最初の追加結果
[image: 最初の追加結果]

既存の値の編集後
[image: 既存の値の編集後]

---

ユーザーマクロ追加が選択できない場合は以下が該当するでしょう。

[ユーザー定義マクロ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=vs-2019#user-defined-macros)

> ユーザー定義マクロは、プロパティ シートに格納されます。 プロジェクトにプロパティシートがまだ含まれていない場合は、[「 Visual Studio プロジェクトの設定を共有または再利用する」](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019)の手順に従って作成できます。

[Visual Studio プロジェクトの設定を共有または再利用する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019)
[プロパティ シートを作成するには](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019#to-create-a-property-sheet)

> 1. メニュー バーで、[ **プロパティ マネージャの表示** > ] または [ **その他の Windows** > **プロパティ マネージャを****表示** > ] を選択します。 **プロパティ マネージャ** が開きます。
> 2. プロパティ シートのスコープを定義するには、適用する項目を選択します。 これは、特定の構成または別のプロパティ シートです。 この項目のショートカット メニューを開き、**[新しいプロジェクト プロパティ シートの追加]** をクリックします。 名前と場所を指定します。
> 3. **プロパティ マネージャ** で、新しいプロパティ シートを開き、含めるプロパティを設定します。

Comment: はい。これも見てみたのですが、これでは、ユーザマクロを追加できても、現在のユーザマクロの値の修正ができないと考えました。
現に、既に追加したマクロがどこにも表れてきていません。

Comment: 「ユーザーマクロの追加」ダイアログで「値」は編集可能なテキストボックスになっていますし、「OK」で終われば、「プロパティページ」ダイアログの「値」欄が変更した値に変わり、「適用」ボタンが有効になります。それで変更出来ました。追加したマクロが表れていないのは、最初の手段(プロジェクトファイルへの直接編集追加)が標準と違うからでは？ いったんプロジェクトファイルを元に戻して、参照記事に説明された方法で追加すれば良いと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: ところが、プロパティマネージャーのどの部分のプロパティシートを選択すればいいのでしょうか？
プロパティシートで「マクロ追加」のボタンが反応しません。
プロパティマネージャのハードコピーを質問に追加します。

Comment: プロパティシートの追加を行ってから、そのプロパティのプロパティシートでマクロの追加、変種ができました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
解決しました。