# Visual studio 2017 DLLのリンクのパスの指定

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2017を使用してます。

Visual Studio 2017のソリューションエクスプローラで以下のように表示される
librariesに表示されているDLLのインポートライブラリのフルパスはどこで、
指定すればいいのでしょうか？ 
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ライブラリ毎にフォルダが異なった場合もありますから、統一して指定できないと
思います。
ライブラリ毎に指定するのではないかと思っていますが、
それを指定する箇所が分かりません。

ご教授ください。

ライブラリ毎のパスの指定の絵
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この記事を参考に。[VisualStudioで外部ライブラリを読み込めるようにする方法](https://corgi-lab.com/windows/vs-external-library/)

Comment: 質問したまま放置しないでください。解決したのであれば解決済みとし、していないのであれば答えて欲しい内容や不足している情報を補足してください。

Comment: https://corgi-lab.com/windows/vs-external-library/
のやり方では、ライブラリが違うフォルダに存在する時、対応できないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 例では1つのフォルダしか指定されていませんが、複数書けますよ。

Comment: ライブラリ毎に、フォルダが指定できるのですか？

Comment: 出来ますよ。こちらの方がもっと具体的でしたか。[ライブラリの使用方法、VisualStudioの設定方法](https://imagingsolution.net/program/how-to-use-library/)

Comment: すみません。分かりませんでした。
「ライブラリファイル(*.lib)の参照設定方法」に書いてある方法でしょうか？
この方法では、ライブラリ単位に違ったフォルダを指定できないと思うのですが、違うでしょうか？

Comment: 少し、進展がありました。
ソリューションプロパティで表示されているライブラリを選択すると、下のプロパティウィンドウにライブラリの情報が出ます。
その「相対パス」の欄が編集できたので、そこにユーザマクロ（$(DevKitPath))を指定したのですが、
リンクを実行すると、ユーザマクロを認識してくれないで、エラーになってしまいました。
ユーザマクロは使用できないのでしょうか？
質問の欄に、画像を追加しました。

Comment: [Visual studio 2017 ユーザマクロの値の変更](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66135/visual-studio-2017-%e3%83%a6%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b6%e3%83%9e%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%81%ae%e5%80%a4%e3%81%ae%e5%a4%89%e6%9b%b4#comment72560_66135)で指摘しましたが、目的に対してユーザーマクロという手段が適切かどうか検討し直すべきだと思います。

Comment: 例えば、同じフォルダパスを何度も使用する必要がある場合、それをマクロという形で、簡潔に記述できるので、使用できれば使用するのが、得策と思います。またフォルダパスが変更になった場合にも、ユーザマクロだけを変更すればいいわけですから、使用したいです。

Comment: つまり、正しい指定方法をするのではなく、ユーザーマクロありきで実現したいということでしょうか？

Comment: 正しい指定方法と書かれましたが。その正しい指定方法には、ユーザマクロの指定は入っていないのでしょうか？
ユーザマクロありきというより、ユーザマクロという便利なものが使用できるのなら、使用したいと考えています。

Answer (score 2):

対象の問題/質問以前に、前提としている環境などへの誤解がありそうです。

**以下は訂正版：**

- ソリューションエクスプローラーのペインに`.lib`ファイルが列挙されていますが、これは依存関係のある(変更されたらビルド処理のトリガとする)ファイルをリストしているのであって、`.cpp`等と類似の扱いになり、拡張子`.lib`が考慮されてリンカに渡されますが、プロジェクトのプロパティダイアログでリンク時のライブラリを指定する際の情報とは違いがあるようです。
- 2つ目のスクリーンショットの右下`ACAP_STATD.lib ファイルのプロパティ`で`相対パス`にユーザーマクロを組み合わせても、完全パスにも有効なパス情報が表示されているように見えますが、マウスポインタを完全パスに当ててフルパスを読み取ると、無効な値になっているのがわかるでしょう。また2つ目のスクリーンショットでも、該当ファイルのアイコンに黄色い三角の！マークが付いていて、無効な指定であることを示しています。
- エラーが発生しているのは、リンク処理時に該当のファイルが見つからないということであって、エラーメッセージを見るとこちらではユーザーマクロは展開されていない形になっています。おそらくソリューションエクスプローラーペインに指定する方法ではユーザーマクロは展開されないものと思われます。
- ソリューションエクスプローラーペインにライブラリファイルを指定する場合は、ユーザーマクロを使わない実際のパス情報そのものを指定する必要があるでしょう。
  ユーザーマクロを有効にしたいのならば、以下の方法で別々に指定を追加する必要があるでしょう。

---

以下記事のように2ステップの作業が必要です。
[ライブラリの使用方法、VisualStudioの設定方法](https://imagingsolution.net/program/how-to-use-library/)

> ライブラリファイル(*.lib)の参照設定方法

1. 「リンカ」の「全般」で **追加のライブラリディレクトリ** を追加する
   ->ここでマクロと組み合わせてディレクトリ指定することも可能です
2. 「リンカ」の「入力」で **追加の依存ファイル** を追加する

**1.** でディレクトリは複数指定可能であり、そこでディレクトリが指定されていれば **2.** ではパス指定は不要でファイル名だけ指定すれば良いわけです。

**1.** の作業をせずに **2.** だけで指定する場合は、そこにフルパスを指定します。

あるいはフルパスを指定するのであれば、上記のように手作業を繰り返すのではなく、ソースコードに記述する方法もあります。
(上記1.でディレクトリを指定しておけばフルパスではなくファイル名指定だけでも出来ます)

> 他にもプログラム中で*.libファイルを直接していする事もできます。
>   例）**#pragma comment(lib,”C:\Program Files\OpenCV\lib\cv.lib”)**

いずれにしろ、最大では `Debug`, `Release`と `Win32`, `x64` の各モードを掛け合わせて4種類の設定を行う必要があります。

ソースコードに記述する場合は、以下のように`#ifdef`のマクロで切り替えられるよう考慮する必要があります。
[ライブラリの設定 | 【C++】VisualStudioの使い方入門](http://visualstudiostudy.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-5.html)

> ライブラリファイルの指定
>   ソースコードに直接記述する方法
>
> 使用するヘッダなどにpragma commentを用いて使用するlibファイルを記述します。上記の例はOpenCV2.3でですが、これはlibファイルがデバッグ用とリリース用の2通りあるためプリプロセッサで場合分けを行っています。

Comment: 質問欄に張り付けた絵を見ていただきたいのですが、ライブライ単位にプロパティで、そのパスが指定できます。
そこに今、ユーザマクロが指定できない事を問題としています。
ユーザマクロを指定する方法を知りたいです。

Comment: 単にそのやり方が間違っているだけでは？ その方法ではマクロを使うことは出来ない可能性が高いと思われます。

Comment: どこが、間違っているのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答の先頭に追記しておきました。